# 0 line style of Chart.js line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a line chart with positive and negative values written in Chart.js.
I'm trying to give the 0 line parallel to the X Axis a colour without affecting other chart elements.

My code:

```
line_chart_options: {
    responsive: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %>: $<%= addThousandCommas(value) %>",
    legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\">&nbsp;</span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
},
```

I tried:

```
    scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
```

But that just colourised the axis, not the 0 line.

How can I colourise the 0 line?

Answer (score 0):

Line Colors are handled by setting the fill colors in the datasets you feed to the chart.  The most notable would be fillColor, strokeColor, and pointColor.

Here is a sample line chart object that colors the 2 lines/series in the chart:

```
var obj=    {
                labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: "My First dataset",
                        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                        pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                        pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        data : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
                    },
                    {
                        label: "My Second dataset",
                        fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                        strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                        pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                        pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                        pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                        data : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
                    }
                ]

            };
```

Comment: I'm not trying to colour the chart data. I'm trying to colour the Axis.

Comment: My mistake.  I did some testing and it seems the only way would be to hardcode a fake series (all zero values).

Comment: Not quite - if there are negative values as well, they will go down from the Axis and the labels will be displayed underneath the negative lines. The X Axis will rest in the middle of the screen.

Comment: I know it can handle negative numbers but since the x-axis labels do not shift up next to the zero line, it goes to show, the concept of the x-axis is different from the mathimatical concept of an x-axis.